# Rails pass records from view to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails 3 app, I have a view that contains search logic.  When the page is viewed the `@events` contains the records to be displayed.

View code:

```
<% @events.each do |event| %>
...
```

I have a button at the bottom of the page to create an Excel spreadsheet using axlsx. I'm trying to pass the @events back to the controller.

This is what I'm trying for the button:

```
  <%= link_to "Excel", event_path("supportlog.xlsx", :events => @events), :class => 'btn btn-warning' %>
```

Then, in the Events controller:

```
  def supportlog
    @events = params[:events]
    @events = Event.find(@events)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.xlsx
    end
  end
```

Before, I've used params to pass one id - this is the first time I'm trying to pass a list.

Thanks for the help!

UPDATE 1

I changed the controller to this:

```
  def index8
    @search = Event.search(params[:q])
    @events = @search.result
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xlsx
    end
  end
```

And the index8 view button to this:

```
<%= link_to "Excel", event_path("index8.xlsx"), :class => 'btn btn-warning' %>
```

But, I need to get the search param back into the controller.

UPDATE 2

This worked:

```
  <%= link_to "Excel", event_path("index8.xlsx", :q => params[:q]), :class => 'btn btn-warning' %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass the search parameters back to the controller. Or even better, make the export part of the search/index (served as a different format).

```
# search is part of the index action
def index
  search_params = params[:search] || {}
  @events = Event.search(search_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {}
    format.json {}
    format.xlsx {}
  end
end
```

Then you can use the search/index URL while specifying the format:
`= link_to 'Export', events_url(search: params[:search], format: :xlsx)`

HTTP passes only parameters between views/forms and server. Rails parses HTTP parameters and constructs the params hash, but not to create AR Objects.

Comment: Using the same search with different format works great!  Thanks!

Comment: I thought it worked.  But, it's actually putting all the events into XLSX. I'll post what I did in my question.

Comment: How do I get the search params back to the controller via the button?

Comment: This worked `  <%= link_to "Excel", event_path("index8.xlsx", :q => params[:q]), :class => 'btn btn-warning' %>`

Comment: Glad it worked. Check you rake routes. If the export is part of the index (not `index8`) - you should be able to use `events_path(q: params[:q])`.